# MYSQL: How dump resultset into a LONGTEXT variable rather than to a output file

Tags: mysql, sql, into-outfile

I want to modify the following code:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\my_excel_table.csv'
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
 FROM mytable;
```

so that it dumps the result into longtext/variable rather than to a output file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can, but there is the [`INSERT ... SELECT FROM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) syntax, which lets you insert the results of a select into another table. Problem is that `SELECT` is going to return rows, which would be inserted one-by-one into the other table, instead of going in as a single long chunk of text.

Comment: thats what i want overcome. As you see from the example. while write file it does by concatenate and using seperators

Answer (score 0):

use [insert select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO mytable (my_field) select my_other_field from my_other_table
```

Comment: I dont want to insert into another field

Comment: may be we can acheive my using group_CONCAT with separators or something

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT's length-limited, though, by default 1024 characters. You can override using the `group_concat_max_len` setting. But if your csv data is "large", you could very well exhaust memory as that group_concat's done purely in memory and won't stream the result into an insert query.